# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" to a static library despite ObjC flag

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I'm getting a runtime error in my application:

> `2011-05-17 09:42:31.124 rxsync[67464:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBodyWithFormMultipartValues:fileNames:contentTypes:usingBoundary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e3cd90'`

This method, `NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBodyWithFormMultipartValues: fileNames: contentTypes: usingBoundary:]`, is defined by a static library that's part of my .xcworkspace.

Here's what I've checked so far:

1. The static library is included in my **Link Binary With Libraries** phase.
2. I have ObjC in the Other Linker Flags (`OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC`) in my application. (In fact, I have it in my static library, too, since it's based on the same xcconfig file.)
3. The signature is the same in my .h and .m file.
4. The static library has **definitely** been rebuilt.
5. I have verified that the object I'm sending the message to is valid.

What possibilities am I missing?

I'm using Xcode 4.0.2. This is an iPhone target.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You additionally need to add -all_load to the Other Linker Flags of the target which is using your static library.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. I saw references to this, but I thought it only applied to Xcode 3. :)

Comment: This fixed my problem too. How were we supposed to know that?

Comment: I came across this problem some time ago and searched in the compiler/linker documentation. It took some time for me to solve this problem....