# Could I extend NSString class in Static Library and use it in App with Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, static-libraries, objective-c-swift-bridge, class-extensions

I extend NSString in my custom static library CommonLib :

```
//NSString+ext.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (ext)
- (BOOL)isContainsEmoji;
@end



//NSString+ext.m
#import "NSString+ext.h"

@implementation NSString (ext)
- (BOOL)isContainsEmoji{
    //Do Something...
}
@end
```

Because CommonLib contains some Swift code files ,so I create a bridging header file CommonLib-Bridging-Header.h in CommonLib project:

```
//in CommonLib-Bridging-Header.h
#import "NSString+ext.h"
```

Next,I link CommonLib to my App project,and create a new file Node.swift in App project:

```
//Node.swift
import Foundation
import CommonLib

class Node{

    var name:String!
    var isBadName:Bool{
        let tmpString = name as NSString
        return tmpString.isContainsEmoji()
    }
}
```

Last,I use it somewhere in my App:

```
//In my UIViewController class
override func viewDidAppear(...){
    super.viewDidAppear(...)

    let node = Node()
    node.name = "panda hopy"
    print("\(node.isBadName)") //Crash in this line!!!
}
```

At this time compile is OK!!! But when I run App it's Crashed:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString isContainsEmoji]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400084b340'

So is something wrong here??? And how to fix it??? Thanks ;)

(PS:my environment Xcode 9.3.1 swift 4.1)

Comment: You can't have bridging headers in libraries, this means you can use swift from Objective-C but not the other way around.

Comment: you mean delete the bridging header file and it will worked???

Comment: More to the point you can have a bridging header, it's just ignored in a static or dynamic library. Libraries and frameworks are not supported for mixed Objective-C and Swift. I was literally told this by an apple dev directly.

Comment: thanks ,but how to fix it???

Comment: You can either use separate frameworks for your swift and objective-c components. Or you can make it so that the Objective-C only calls into the swift and never vice versa. You can sort of get around that by using dynamic instantiation and using protocols defined in swift... but be wary of ref count issues that crop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I'm glad to fixed this Q ;)

It's very easy, add link option to App project :

> -all_load

That's all right ,you can refer to this :

[unrecognized selector sent to instance” to a static library despite ObjC flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034283/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-to-a-static-library-despite-objc-flag)

Thanks everyone ;)